# jQuery validation does not validate any form field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application which generates the following view:

```
<form method="post" id="Form1" action="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/cgi-pgms/xlsrdr.exe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 text-left">
                                Submit Payroll
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 text-left">
                                <input id="achaccounts" type="hidden" value="xxxx" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Sheet">Sheet Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sheet" aria-describedby="sheetHelp" placeholder="Sheet name">
                                    <small id="sheetHelp" class="form-text text-muted">If Sheet Name is not supplied, the first sheet in the file is assumed.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Contact">Contact Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="Contact" aria-describedby="contactHelp" value="First Last">
                                    <small id="contactHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Name of contact person in case of payroll submission problems.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="EMail">eMail Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="EMail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="xxxxx@gmail.com">
                                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">eMail address of contact person in case of payroll submission problems.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Phone">Contact Phone Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="Phone" aria-describedby="phoneHelp" value="1234567890">
                                    <small id="phoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Phone number of contact person in case of payroll submission problems.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="PayDate">Pay Date</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="PayDate" name="PayDate" aria-describedby="paydateHelp" autocomplete="off" placeholder="From Date" value="">
                                    <small id="paydateHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Payroll ending date for the submitted payroll (MM/DD/YYYY format).</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="DolAmt">Total Dollar Amount</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="DolAmt" aria-describedby="dolAmtHelp" placeholder="0.00">
                                    <small id="dolAmtHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Total dollar amount of payroll including all contributions and loan repayments.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="DepAmt">Deposit Amount</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="DepAmt" aria-describedby="depAmtHelp" placeholder="0.00">
                                    <small id="depAmtHelp" class="form-text text-muted">The sum of the Deposit Amount plus the Amount Used From Forfeitures (if any) must equal the Total Dollar Amount.</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="DepMeth">Select a Deposit Method</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="DepMeth">
                                            <option value="WIRE" selected>ACH Payment / Wire</option>
                                            <option value="CHECK">Check</option>
                                            <option value="ACH">ACH Collection</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
        var date_PayDate = $('input[name="PayDate"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        var options = {
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        };
        date_PayDate.datepicker(options);
    })</script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Form1").validate({
            // Specify validation rules
            rules:
                {
                Contact: "required",
                EMail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                Phone: {
                    required: true,
                    phoneUS: true
                    },
                PayDate: {
                    required: true,
                    dateBR: true
                    },
                DolAmt: {
                    required: true,
                    min: 0,
                    number: true
                    },
                DepAmt: {
                    required: true,
                    min: 0,
                    number: true
                    },
                },

                });
        });

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateBR", function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/.test(value);
        }, "Enter a valid date in MM/DD/YYYY format)");
    </script>
    <script>
        $("Form1").validate();
    </script>
```

In my heading, I have the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

When I execute the code, and clear out the Contact name and the phone number, I expected the validation to generate a default error.  Nothing gets generated. No javascript errors are generated to the console.

Do I need to define what error message gets displayed for each rule? Also, how do I define where the error message will get displayed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your fields contain a `name` attribute.

```
...
rules: {
    Contact: "required",
    EMail: { ...
```

The identifiers that you have configured are designed to hook back to the `name` attribute.

```
<input name="Contact" ....
<input name="EMail" ....
```